# WHERE HAVING COUNT(*) Very slow query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a SQL query which takes 32 sec to complete,
any ideas how to run it faster?

```
SELECT accounts.*
FROM accounts
WHERE accounts.account_id IN (SELECT map.account_id 
                              FROM  map 
                              WHERE map.account_id=accounts.account_id                              
                              HAVING COUNT(*)<2) 
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what is performance like without the order by rand()? is it much faster?

Comment: Is there any index created on the column accounts(account_id) and map(account_id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inner join to achieve that filtering:

```
SELECT accounts.*
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT map.account_id
    FROM map
    GROUP BY map.account_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
    ) AS m ON accounts.account_id = m.account_id
ORDER BY rand() 
limit 1
```

I'm not sure why you are ordering by rand or limiting the result to 1 but could it be repetitive execution of this overall query is a performance issue?

Comment: Works Great, mil sec query,
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some interesting takeaways from this solution.

Comment: The lesson:  Using a derived query (`JOIN/FROM ( SELECT ...)`) is often faster than `IN(SELECT...)` or even `EXISTS(SELECT ...)`.   Or at least, you should try such.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting In clause to EXISTS clause -

```
SELECT accounts.*
  FROM accounts
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM map 
                WHERE map.account_id=accounts.account_id 
                GROUP BY map.account_id
               HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
               ) 
ORDER BY rand() 
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, same results 32 sec query.